# How can I add a custom control inherited from an existing one, then be able to retrieve it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, custom-controls

I have created a new class that inherits from TextBox class, by doing:

```
Public Class mTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Dim field As String
    Public Property FieldName()
        Get
            Return field
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            field = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I then created a set of dynamic `mTextBox`es and added them onto a form, by doing:

```
Dim frm As New Form
Dim mtb As New mTextBox
mtb.Text = "my text"
mtb.FieldName = "field_name"
frm.controls.add(mtb)
mtb.SetBounds(20, 20, 100, 20)
frm.Show()
```

That works fine and I am able to see the textbox appearing on the form.
But when I try to iterate through all of the controls on the form to fetch the `.Text` and `.FieldName`, no control is detected, so no single iteration is executed. Here is my code that iterates through all controls on the form

```
Sub savecustomer()
        Dim fields As String = ""
        Dim values As String = ""
        For Each t In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (t) Is mTextBox Then
                Dim TB As mTextBox = DirectCast(t, mTextBox)
                fields &= TB.FieldName & ","
                values &= "'" & TB.Text & "',"
            End If
        Next
        fields = fields.Substring(0, fields.Length - 1)
        values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1)

        Dim sql As String = String.Format("insert into customers ({0}) values ({1})", fields, values)
        Execute_SQL(sql)

    End Sub
```

I tried changing the for loop a bit:

```
For Each t In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (t) Is TextBox Then
         Dim TB As mTextBox = DirectCast(t, mTextBox) 'This line throws exception
                  'The exception is : cannot cast TextBox to mTextBox
         fields &= TB.FieldName & ","
         values &= "'" & TB.Text & "',"
    End If
Next
```

If I change the above code by replacing each mTextBox with TextBox then the code will work but I would lose the ability to fetch the .FieldName since it is not a member of TextBox

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the SameCustomer method?

Comment: @MattWilko Did you mean SaveCustomer? I declared it on the same form code page

Comment: Anyway, usually these kind of problems aren't solved by inheriting Controls. You could use a Dictionary(Of TextBox, String) and bind TextBox to their values (you can even bind to a class/struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the right form. When you create the new form `Dim frm As New Form` it doesn't have a method named `savecustomer`.

```
Sub savecustomer()
    For Each t In Me.Controls '<- NOT frm
    Next
End Sub
```

Change your save method to include a `Form` parameter:

```
Sub savecustomer(frm As Form)
    For Each t In frm.Controls
        '...
    Next
End Sub
```

Then pass the form you wish to save to `savecustomer`:

```
Dim frm As New Form
'...
savecustomer(frm)
```

Comment: How did I miss that. Thanks very much. It IS obvious that I have created frm in a context and never referred to the same form later.